# NodeJS Cluster2 - Identifying, by pid, which cluster is responding to requests

Tags: node.js

Using the cluster2 example for express apps:
(https://github.com/ql-io/cluster2)

```
var Cluster = require('cluster2'),
    express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

var = clusterID;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Cluster: ", clusterID);
    res.send('hello');
});

var c = new Cluster({
    port: 3000,
});

c.on('forked', function(pid) {
    clusterID = pid;
    console.log('Worker ' + pid + ' forked');
});

c.listen(function(cb) {
    cb(app);
});
```

I am attempting to determine which cluster is responding to the get request for '/'.

Trying to capture the pid in a variable, when the worker is forked, is not working, and I do not understand why.

This is my solution, however the clusterID is undefined in all cases except inside the 'forked' function. (I have added the variable clusterID on line 5, the console.log inside the get('/'... statement, and set the var clusterID to the respective pid, when that worker is forked.

I was under the impression that forked workers all used their own instance of the server, and thus the pid would be set once that worker is forked, for the duration of the instance. Is this incorrect?

Thank you

Note - I could not create a tag cluster2 (reputation limitation), or choose cluster as a tag. If someone can tag this properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.pid` will give you the current pid, even inside a cluster worker. So this works:

```
var Cluster = require('cluster2'),
    express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Cluster: ", process.pid);
    res.send('hello');
});

var c = new Cluster({
    port: 3000,
});

c.on('forked', function(pid) {
    console.log('Worker ' + pid + ' forked');
});

c.listen(function(cb) {
    cb(app);
});
```

Comment: I must have been thrown off by their callback functions receiving pid. d'oh! Thanks!